# what is monotonicity and strict monotonicity in preferences?

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, consumer-theory, preferences, demand

I am really confused between monotonic preferences and strictly monotonic preferences, I saw some video and **read certain answer where it is mentioned that the**

- When preferences are monotone / weak monotonic preference, the
  consumer prefers more of both goods.
- When preferences are strictly    monotone or having strong monotonic
  preference, the consumer prefers    more of one good but no less of
  the other.

(source: https://www.learnpick.in/questions/details/11169/what-is-a-monotonic-preference)

**whereas when I read this other paper it says**

- Monotonicity means that if c1 contains more of some or all
  commodities, but no less of any, than c2 (c1 ≥ c2) then c1 ≿ c2.
- Strict monotonicity means that if c1 contains more of each commodity
  than c2 (c1 > c2) then c1 strictly prefered c2

(source: [http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2008/REUPapers/Shon.pdf](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/VIGRE/VIGRE2008/REUPapers/Shon.pdf))

I am confused as both the answers are quite contradicting as the (first as per sequence I mentioned) says that in strict preferences the consumer more of at least one good but no less of the other.

whereas (second as per sequence I mentioned) says in strict monotonicity we prefer more of both the goods. Also, I am able to understand the graphical representation of the monotonicity.
Please tell me where I am getting it wrong I am really stuck on this.
Thank you.

Comment: See the first para of [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_preferences) page on monotonic preferences. Does this answer your question?

Comment: There is no uniform terminology. The second source is really unreliable and looks like the notes of some confused undergraduate student.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word monotonic means "always moving in the same direction", in our case, always going up.

Monotonic preferences mean that the customer **always** prefers more of a good.

This comes in two flavors:

1. Strictly monotonic: More of one good is always preferred to less of that good.
2. Weakly monotonic: More of one good is always equivalent or better than less of that good.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. Just one more doubt: 
so we will represent Strict monotonicity as c1 ≻ c2 (where c1 has more of both the goods)Weakly monotonicity as c1 ≿ c2 (where c1 has more of at least one of two good but no less of the other good)

Comment: Minor edit: The content in parens should be the same for both: Strict monotonicity as c1 ≻ c2 (where c1 has more of at least one good but no less of  any other good) Weakly monotonicity as c1 ≿ c2 (where c1 has more of at least one good but no less of any other good)

Comment: okay, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Sir, where can I find a graphical representation of strictly and weakly monotonic preferences? If you have any idea or suggestion for the references please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: The Cobb-Douglas function $U(L,K) = L^\alpha * K^{1-\alpha}$ is strictly monotonic in preferences. Plot it with U on the vertical and it will be a nice smooth arch increasing in L and K.